# Drop Shadow On & Off Image

Tags: html, dropshadow

Drop Shadow On & Off Image

What is the code to do this?
The html section is where I need help, maybe everywhere else too  : )

See codepen
https://codepen.io/davidhelp/pen/Babqmqo?editors=1100

```
   img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) 5px 9px 9px;
    }

   .img1 {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="cell1"><img src="minion2.jpg" width="117" height="165" alt=""><br>1 shadow</div>

    <div class="cell2"><img src="minion2.jpg" width="117" height="165" alt=""><br>2 no shadow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to add "img2" class in the 2nd image.
write

```html
<img class="img2" src="minion2.jpg" width="117" height="165" alt="">
```

Or, in the css; you can target the parent container like this:

```css
.cell2 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added only this part:

 <img class="img1" src="minion2.jpg" width="117" height="165" alt="">

I kept the .cell2 as is:

.cell2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none !important;

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved and an upvote.

Comment: It's very strange that someone asks a question and did not give any upvote, mark the answer as solved. It demotivate others to answer any questions.

Comment: See result: https://davidswebsite.com/stackoverflow/shadow_on_off.html

Comment: Did you see what I have commented?

Comment: Do not get too upset. I do not have permission yet "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."